# How to override default behavior of END button in InputField, in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

I'm trying to create a simple text editor in Unity.

Right now, I'm trying to override the standard <kbd>End</kbd> keyboard key functionality.

I'm using the "new" UI system and an `InputField` as the text editor.
It has multi-line enabled. Normally when you hit <kbd>End</kbd> (on a normal physical keyboard) when the focus is on the `InputField`, the caret goes to the end of the entire `TextField`. I want it to go to just the end of the current line. Basically I want the same functionality that you have in normal text editors like Notepad++.

So far, I have a script on the `InputField` that goes like this:

```
public InputField editor; // This is the InputField

void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.End))
    {
        string code = editor.text;
        int caretPos = editor.caretPosition;

        int newLineIndex = FindEndOfLine(code, caretPos);
        editor.caretPosition = newLineIndex;
    }
}

int FindEndOfLine(string text, int startIndex)
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(text[i]);

        if (text[i] == '\n')
        {
            Debug.Log("FOUND IT: " + i);
            return i;
        }
    }

    return text.Length;
}
```

If I use this for another key, like `KeyCode.Y`, then it works pretty well. It finds the correct caret position and moves the caret to that place. However, it then also prints the character `Y`.

When I use `KeyCode.End` and hit the <kbd>End</kbd> key, it just goes to the end of the entire `TextField`. So I'm thinking my code works, but that it performs the normal <kbd>End</kbd> key functionality after my script has been executed.

How do I prevent this default behavior? I've been Googling for 25 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution. You should inherit `InputField` class, override `Rebuild` method in order to save `CaretPosition` and override `LateUpdate` method to change the behaviour of the <kbd>End</kbd> key. When you're done replace `InputField` component on your `GameObject` with your `CustomInputField` script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CustomInputField : InputField
{
    private int oldCaretPosition;

    public override void Rebuild(CanvasUpdate update)
    {
        base.Rebuild(update);
        oldCaretPosition = caretPosition;
    }

    protected override void LateUpdate()
    {
        base.LateUpdate();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.End))
        {
            int newLineIndex = FindEndOfLine(oldCaretPosition);
            caretPosition = newLineIndex;
        }
    }

    private int FindEndOfLine(int startIndex)
    {
        for (int i = startIndex; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] == '\n')
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return text.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'm going to google it, but could you briefly explain what the LateUpdate and Rebuild methods do and why I need to put the KeyDown handler here instead of as a separate script?

Comment: So the logic is the following. First of all we need to save caret position before it is moved to the end of the text. I tried to find a method which could be overriden and save the caret position. It turned out that `Rebuild` method is suitable for the purpose. I picked up this method just by my guess. As documentation says, `Rebuild` method rebuilds the input fields geometry. (caret and highlight). `LateUpdate` is called after all `Update` functions have been called. So it gives me an opportunity to move caret to the end of the line after it has been moved to the end of the text.